# Ag-Grid, Tooltip Issue -- if empty value is changed to some value, tooltip is not shown fro that cell

Tags: reactjs, tooltip, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

In the below example first row, the first cell, if we change the value to new value, the tooltip is not rendered on hover.

For other nonempty cells, it's working fine.

Total code is present here https://plnkr.co/edit/r4JbPris8GwibYs6?preview

```
          <AgGridReact
            columnDefs={this.state.columnDefs}
            defaultColDef={this.state.defaultColDef}
            tooltipShowDelay={this.state.tooltipShowDelay}
            rowData={this.state.rowData}
            frameworkComponents={this.state.frameworkComponents}
            onGridReady={this.onGridReady}
          />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Empty fields don't [show tooltip](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-tooltip-component/#showing-blank-values) unless you use tooltipValueGetter:

```
{
  field: 'athlete',
  minWidth: 150,
  tooltipValueGetter: function(params) {
    return { value: params.value };
},
```

Comment: It's fine if it doesn't load tooltip if it's empty. But after the cell value edit it is still not working

Comment: after editing a empty cell to some value , tootlip is still not shown

Comment: can you edit the first cell and add some value. After the value is added, still tooltip is not shown

Comment: why. it seems to be a bug ?

Comment: if there is some text it should show the tooltip right ?

Comment: same issue after adding that also https://plnkr.co/edit/PigHchVV8cTGmqzh

Comment: @VinodSai you have to use tooltipValueGetter instead of tooltipField, so remove tooltipField.